# Rendering line-arcs polylines with windows GDI

Tags: c++, windows, gdi+, gdi, polyline

I have to render on screen a sequence of 2D lines and circular arcs (constant radius) connected to each other, forming a continuous path (the tangent may still have discontinuities, so it's just *C0*). This is a typical task in CNC machinery GUIs.

Each element of the path can be generalized as:

```
struct Gline
{
    int x,y; // [pix] Destination point
    double bulge; // Normalized sagitta (0:straight-line, 1:half-circle)

    void get_center_and_radius(int& xc, int& yc, int& r) const; // Makes sense just for arcs (bulge not zero)
};
```

where *bulge* (`tan(arc_angle_span/4)`) represents somewhat the "curviness" of the line, if zero the line is straight, if one the line is a semicircle, ecc...
From these data (actually is needed also the starting point, but that's not important in this context) you can calculate the center and radius of the arc.

My current solution uses the windows GDI functions `LineTo` and `Arc`:

```
const double toll = 1E-6;
// HDC hdc; // Device context
int x_from = x_start, // The starting point
    y_from = y_start;
::MoveTo(hdc, x_from, y_from);
std::vector<Gline> gpolyline;
for( const Gline& gline : gpolyline )
   {
    if( std::fabs(gline.bulge) < toll )
       {// Straight line
        ::MoveTo(hdc, x_from, y_from);
        ::LineTo(hdc, gline.x, gline.y);
       }
    else
       {// Arc
        int xc=0, yc=0; // [pix] Center coordinates
        int r = 0; // [pix] Radius
        gline.get_center_and_radius(xc,yc,r);
        if( gline.bulge > toll )
           {// Positive arc
            ::Arc(hdc, xc-r, yc-r, xc+r, yc+r, x_from, y_from, gline.x, gline.y);
           }
        else
           {// Negative arc
            ::Arc(hdc, xc-r, yc-r, xc+r, yc+r, gline.x, gline.y, x_from, y_from);
           }
       }
    x_from = gline.x;
    y_from = gline.y;
   }
```

This somewhat works, but the problem with this approach is that lines and arcs aren't really connected, there's no constraint that indicates that the destination point of a line/arc is coincident with the starting point of the next arc.
This becomes apparent when zooming the viewport too much such as the numeric errors in `get_center_and_radius` function become painfully visible.
I was looking for a `PolyLine`/`PolyDraw` like function for lines and arcs, I'm wondering if there's a smart way to adapt `PolyDraw` to approximate arcs but I'm not sure if it can be done or would be worth it.
I'm seeking advice if my solution can be improved in the Windows GDI realm, how others may have approached this, or if I just have to use an external graphic library.

Comment: have you looked at AngleArc?  Pretty sure drawing by 'current position' gets poly-line-like behavior.

Comment: @Abel I'm reading its documentation now with more attention thanks to your comment, surely is worth a try!

Comment: @Abel Tried `AngleArc` and I think I'll keep it since plays much better with `LineTo`. If you want to expand a little your comment in an answer, I'll accept it.